# Importing a single column CSV into MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv

I am having some trouble importing a CSV file with 232 million rows into a MySQL database table. I am trying to use the following code:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'MyCSV.csv' INTO TABLE MyTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
ENCLOSED '\N'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Part of the problem is the data I am working with is just one 10 digit number per line and no formatting for example:

```
1234567890 
0987654321
5432167890
```

I'm trying to account for the fact that I only have one field, so I don't really to worry about what fields are terminated by, but that field doesn't have anything it is enclosed by.

Is there a way I can use infile to import my data without editing the file first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply use:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'MyCSV.csv' INTO TABLE MyTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Or maybe just:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'MyCSV.csv' INTO TABLE MyTable
```